# Preset-based style and labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

I would like to create two presets in QGIS 2.18 that are displaying the same layers, but the first preset using one labels/colors and the second preset using another labels/colors.

As a workaround, I "duplicate" the layer and display the original layer for preset A and the "duplicate" for preset B, with two different labels & style. 
However this can create a lot of duplicate layers in big projets.

Is there a function "preset" to define the rule-based labelling and the rule-based style?

Comment: are you using shapefiles or tables from a postgres server?

Comment: I m using shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand well your need but you can add several different style to the same layer (right click on a layer then Styles>Add... , you need to add a new style before modifying it)

After that you can define different preset (using the eyes icon) with the style you want for each layer

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for! It works for both style and label ! Thanks

Comment: Tried it **for style** : it is ok for me ... but how did u play with presets and labeling (_without duplicating layers of course_) ?

Comment: Theoricaly the style include labelling, if you want same representation (symbol color and size) but different label you have to create a new style then change the labeling property